# Setting dedicated tez queue in R Studio

Tags: r, hive

I have an R code which connects to hive using a JDBC driver. I have been able to setup a successful connection and can also query the underlying tables.

The issue is coming because all my queries are getting in the default queue while we have a separate dedicated queue created exclusively for us. So while my smaller queries are running, larger ones are taking a long time since all goes to default queue and not the specific one which is dedicated for my use.

I am looking the equivalent of,

```
Set tez.queue.name= my queue;
```

Can someone please help how I can set this up before I start extracting the data for analysis purposes? I am using a connection (conn) such as,

```
Sample-Data <- dbGetQuery(conn, paste0(‘my sql statement which I want to execute’))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a connection first and then use `dbExecute` to pass the parameters you want to hive.

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
library(dbplyr)
iniHdp <- function(){ 
              con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "your_data_base")
              dbExecute(con,"tez.queue.name= your_queue")
              }
```

Then you connect to it and proceed with your query, for example, I use dplyr to read a table

```
cntcn <- iniHdp()
tb1 <- tbl(cntcn ,in_schema('you_schema','your_table'))
tb1 %>% glimpse()
```